# can't access json data using dot notation, it's really weird

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux

This is a really weird problem I've never seen before. I'm only able to refer to a certain level in the JSON file using dot notation, then it's not recognized at all and returns undefined, even though the data is definitely defined.

I haven't found anything online about this at all so I'm hoping someone else has run into this problem before.

Here's a link to one of the JSON files I'm working with, I used myjson.com to create it: https://api.myjson.com/bins/revu0

Here's my data request which works fine except for 1 thing.

```
export const fetchPosts = () => {

return async dispatch => {
    const response = await jsonPlaceholder.get('https://api.myjson.com/bins/15iffs');

    dispatch({ type: 'FETCH_POSTS', payload: response.data.apartments })
  }
}
```

Notice I write response.data.aparmtents, this is because if I don't write it here I cannot access it in my other files.

In this one file, I cannot access the .adress, it returns undefined. I can read other properties, just not that one.

```
import './ApartmentCountTitle.css';
import React from 'react';
import { connect } from 'react-redux';
import ToolTip from '../ToolTip/ToolTip';

const ApartmentCountTitle = (props) => {
   console.log(props.apts[0].address)
  return (
    <div className="ApartmentCountTitle containerapttitle">
      <div>558 of 889 Listings In </div>
      <div className="tooltip">
        <ToolTip />
      </div>
    </div>
  );
}


const mapStateToProps = (state) => {
  return { apts: state.PostsReducer }
}

export default connect(mapStateToProps)(ApartmentCountTitle);
```

In this other file, I can access some of the data I need, but I really want to access the data at the base level of the response here, and can't do that either, it also returns undefined. Even the dot notation is exactly the same.

import './ApartmentList.css';

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { connect } from 'react-redux';
import { fetchPosts } from '../../actions';
import Grid from '@material-ui/core/Grid';

class PostList extends Component {

  componentDidMount() {
    this.props.fetchPosts();
  }

  renderList() {
    if(this.props.apts) {
      return this.props.apts.map(apartment => {
        return (
          <Grid key={apartment._id} item lg={4} md={6} xs={12}> 
            <div> 
              <img style={{objectFit: 'cover'}} src={apartment.images.photos[0].path} alt="" width='100%' height="150px"/>
              <div className="containeraps">
                <div className='aptprice'>{apartment.pricing.price} €</div>
                <div className="monthutil">
                  <div>Per Month</div>
                  <div>Utilities incl.</div>
                </div>
              </div>
              <div className="movein">
                from 29.24.2019 - {parseInt(apartment.details.squareMeters)} m² - {apartment.bedroomCount} bedroom
              </div>
            </div>
          </Grid>
        )
      })
    }
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div className='aptlist'>
        <Grid container spacing={24}>
          {this.renderList()}
        </Grid>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

const mapStateToProps = (state) => {
  return { apts: state.PostsReducer }
}

export default connect(mapStateToProps,
  {fetchPosts}
)(PostList);

import './ApartmentList.css';
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { connect } from 'react-redux';
import { fetchPosts } from '../../actions';
import Grid from '@material-ui/core/Grid';

class PostList extends Component {

  componentDidMount() {
    this.props.fetchPosts();
  }

  renderList() {
    if(this.props.apts) {
      return this.props.apts.map(apartment => {
        return (
          <Grid key={apartment._id} item lg={4} md={6} xs={12}> 
            <div> 
              <img style={{objectFit: 'cover'}} src={apartment.images.photos[0].path} alt="" width='100%' height="150px"/>
              <div className="containeraps">
                <div className='aptprice'>{apartment.pricing.price} €</div>
                <div className="monthutil">
                  <div>Per Month</div>
                  <div>Utilities incl.</div>
                </div>
              </div>
              <div className="movein">
                from 29.24.2019 - {parseInt(apartment.details.squareMeters)} m² - {apartment.bedroomCount} bedroom
              </div>
            </div>
          </Grid>
        )
      })
    }
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div className='aptlist'>
        <Grid container spacing={24}>
          {this.renderList()}
        </Grid>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

const mapStateToProps = (state) => {
  return { apts: state.PostsReducer }
}

export default connect(mapStateToProps,
  {fetchPosts}
)(PostList);
```

I hope I'm explaining this clearly, it's a really weird issue and I'm completely stumped. Never had trouble using dot notation to access data, no matter how big the file was.

```
export default (state = [], action) => {
  switch(action.type) {
    case 'FETCH_POSTS':
      return action.payload;
    default:
      return state;
  }
}
```

Comment: Can you post the code of `PostsReducer`?

Comment: just included it at the bottom

Comment: Can you check (in Redux dev tools for example) what is the shape of your store after a dispatch?

Answer (score 0):

You're unable to access `props.apts[0].address` because when component loads initially there is no data available in initial state of reducer, you get data after http calls. You're able to access data in `PostList` component , because u have added if condition inside render.

Comment: I added a conditional in the renderLIst() function but now the data doesn't load at all

Comment: additionally, when I run console.log(this.props.apts.data) the data is shown, but when I run console.log(this.props.apts.data.apartments), I get an undefined error even though it's defined.

Comment: Thats strange, can u try accessing using bracket notation this.props.apts.data['apartments']. If doesn't work even Fiddle would help.